# How to set a Macro to run automatically in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, macros

I have the follow macro to select the entire word under caret

```
select-word caret-begin-word selection-end-word
```

here I sit to trigger when ctrl+d is pressed.
it works.

Is there a way to trigger the macro automatically?
I mean, I want the word to be fully selected when the caret is over it without the need to press ctrl+d.

Answer (score 0):

### Select word without pressing ctrl+d

- Use the mouse to drag-select the region of text.
- Use ctrl+shift+right to extend selection to the right
- Use ctrl+shift+left to extend the selection to the left